# Image upload form works for some but not others?

Tags: php, image, forms, upload

I have an image upload form that works great! For me... It seems almost everyone else gets an error! How in the world can this be? (I know my programming is sloppy, I'm not looking for criticism, just a quick fix! Please help.)

Form:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="imgupload.php" method="POST">
Image upload:
<input name="uploadedfile" type="file" />
<input type="submit" value="Upload" />
</form>
```

Form Handler:

```
<?php

if (($_FILES["uploadedfile"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
&& ($_FILES["uploadedfile"]["size"] < 4000000))
{


  // Where the file is going to be placed 
  $target_path = "/images/";


  /* Add the original filename to our target path.  
  Result is "images/filename.extension" */

//////////RENAME FILE/////////////


$filetype = pathinfo($_FILES['uploadedfile']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);  
$oldtitle =  $_FILES["uploadedfile"]["name"];
$take_file_extension = substr($oldtitle, 0, strrpos($oldtitle, '.'));
$title = "jeep_".$take_file_extension.".".$filetype;


  $target_path = $target_path . $title;


if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {

  echo "The picture ".  basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']). 
  " has been uploaded<br><br>----------------<br><br>";

  echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["uploadedfile"]["name"] . "<br>";
  echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["uploadedfile"]["size"] / 1024) . " Kb<br>";

    }
}



else
{
    echo "There is a file size limit of 1MB. Only JPG's can be uploaded!";
}
?>
```

Works for me every time, everyone else get's the "There is a file size limit of 1MB. Only JPG's can be uploaded!" error.

Comment: May be they are uploading png, gif, bmp?

Comment: Nope, not working for jpgs specifically.

Answer (score 0):

Even though your code is set to accept images up to 4MB, you have to tell PHP to allow images of this size, by editing the value of a few php.ini settings:

- [upload_max_filesize](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.upload-max-filesize)
- [post_max_size](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.post-max-size)

And the reason why you can only upload .jpg images is because your conditional is restricted to .jpg:

```
if (($_FILES["uploadedfile"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
```

Try a switch:

```
switch ($_FILES["uploadedfile"]["type"]) {

    case 'image/jpeg':
    case 'image/png':
        break;

    default:
        throw new Exception('Invalid image type');
}
```

Comment: The fact that they can't upload ANY size image (not even a 40kb img), tells me that it can't be the php.ini settings. I have my php.ini settings set up to allow 1024M. I believe this is the max? No luck.

Comment: Ahhh, the "There is a file size limit of 1MB. Only JPG's can be uploaded" must be a related to type, not size, focus on the file type then.

Comment: The other weird thing is that I CAN upload the exact same image that they can't.

Comment: @user1142872 What is the error they are getting? Anything? Put some debugging in your script, maybe enable PHP errors to report to the page, and then come back and let us know that error.

Comment: For the record you didn't state that you and others were uploading the same exact image. I inferred that you were uploading jpg, and the others were uploading .png or .gif.

Comment: @user1142872 Try not even limiting the file type and see if the image uploads.

Comment: @user1142872: Did removing the file type restriction help?

Answer (score 0):

I'm wondering if it is your max_execution_time in php.ini.  Try changing to above 30.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time

Slower (lower bandwidth) connections may take longer to upload larger images causing it to error out, your connection could be faster.

Comment: I've been running into the same issue as well.  I changed memory_limit and max_input_time as well.  I'm testing now to see if that fixed anything.